# A sum over partitions involving "subpartitions"

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions, permutation-groups

Consider the following sum over partitions of $n$:

$$ S(n)=\sum_{\substack {j_1,\dots,j_n\geq 0\\j_1+2j_2+\dots+nj_n=n}} \prod_{t=1}^n \frac{1}{j_t!t^{j_t}}f_t(j_1,\dots,j_t),$$

where

$$ f_t(j_1,\dots,j_t)=\begin{cases}\frac{j_t}{j_t+1}\,&\textrm{if } j_1+2j_2+\dots+(t-1)j_{t-1}=t-1 \\1 \,&\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

I have strong numerical evidence that

$$ S(n)=\frac{1}{n+1},$$

but I cannot prove it, I was wondering if anyone could give me ideas.

[image]

Some observations: I wasn't able to compute it using a simple generating function, since I would need $f_t(j_1,\dots,j_t)$ to be a function only of $j_t$.

The function $$f(j_1,\dots, j_n)=\prod_{t=1}^n f_t(j_1,\dots,j_t)$$ can also be intepreted as a function of the cycle structure of a permutation depending on which "subpartitions" $j_1,\dots, j_n$ contains, or on the invariant subsets of $\{1,\dots, n\}$ under the permutations with the cycle structure given by the partition. $S(n)$ can be seen as the average of $f$ over the permutation group, since the $\prod_{t=1}^n \frac{1}{j_t!t^{j_t}}$ is the probability of drawing a permutation with $j_k$ $k-$cycles in its decomposition.

Ideally, I would like to compute, or at least bound

$$ S(n,x)=\sum_{\substack {j_1,\dots,j_n\geq 0\\j_1+2j_2+\dots+nj_n=n}} \prod_{t=1}^n \frac{x^{j_t}}{j_t!t^{j_t}}f_t(j_1,\dots,j_t),$$

for $x>0$, but I don't have a good conjecture on the form of this sum, except for $x=1$.

Comment: The easy bounds are $\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!(n+1)} \le S(n, x) \le \binom{x-1+n}{n} - \frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}$, since the coefficient of $x^n$ is given by the term with $j_1 = n$ and the rest of the upper bound follows from $f_t(j_1, \ldots, j_t) \le 1$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor thank you for the comment! I had only found the first term of this upper bound until now. I unfortunately need an upper bound that decays at least as $1/n$. I'm hoping that whatever technique allows to show the closed form for $x=1$ might shed light on how to compute or upper bound the other cases.

Comment: It would automatically give you an upper bound, because all of the coefficients are non-negative so for $x > 0$ we have $S(n, x)  \le \frac{x^n}{(n-1)!(n+1)} + \left(S(n,1) - \frac{1}{(n-1)!(n+1)}\right) \max(x, x^{n-1})$.

Comment: Any ideas from the answer to this question? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224154/a-remarkable-sum-over-partitions   as well as some applications on this blog post linked to in the above answer? https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/06/24/gila-vi-the-cycle-index-polynomials-of-the-symmetric-groups/

Comment: [Sage code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9UU1rwzAMvedX6Gg3WRpfx3zfYYeVHccoYVaGIJaLo0Dpr1-UmZBSmE6234efpIADvL1-GLbPFSyVcQIPp1N7w5yMXd-GlGHsIxDDe5-FhBJPm0KrDwE5_AkTo7FwVEXbz1I8tOI8BvqWhaaYpDNeL2d92XEokgYo1JYE47SDNYpokNzzDxrXANduF2S1GGCaoyE4QKRVYahZjlZ1q__CIHgBseA9yJO71xeP9ZuS45Gw6_qwxf2Ur6Vxs7vV4OyDFscJ_3X00G2wLqT2BSkrkjmzAlWl3fHdPFzXlXlcMrEYbsp-tVd3NDov-wtZan-j&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) checking the claim for all $n \leq 45$.

Comment: [$S(n,x)$ for $n \leq 200$](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw9jt9qgzAUxq_NU3yXSVut9rLUsieQtTLY1Yq4kzaoicSEubff0ZYFEg7n9_2J9m6AjrYNzvUTzDA6H9D7eGub9kFCVChxyHMhrsbeP7PTfObFu-t_rRtM0y9bebmoFX9kp_jEP-Rr8oamla_WHb5JN7EPt9FTy6oKWxyUEG__bbJylpRgHa6yU0eRGI0OZYn8CE8heouCXfkmioQ4QsavDhvM2KNTGc2jVCJ5CYkBp6SFQgpJ_PC0R-Q7M1p89YrFWlg_C1_mpT6bHkYHmXZK5izSzsPCWPjG3vmr24L14DN6Y4O0O46wSv0BkqNgUw==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==). On this basis I'm making two conjectures: if $n \ge 2^k$ then $[x^k] S(n,x) = 0$; and $[x^k] S(2^k - 1, x) = 2^{-k(k+1)/2}$.

Comment: Working from that data, it seems that $$S(n,x) = \frac1{(n-1)!(n+1)}x^n + \frac{n-2}{2! (n-1)!} x^{n-1} + \frac{n(3n - 10)}{4! (n-2)!} x^{n-2} + \frac{5n(3n^2 - 15n + 6)}{6!(n-3)!} x^{n-3} + \frac{7n(15n^3 - 105n^2 + 110n - 8)}{8!(n-4)!} x^{n-4} + \frac{315n(3n^4 - 28n^3 + 53n^2 - 16n - 4)}{10!(n-5)!} x^{n-5} + \cdots + O(x^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor})$$. The coefficients of the polynomials don't appear to be in OEIS, although maybe it's a case of finding the right scaling factor from each one's content.

Comment: @PeterTaylor wow, thank you! I was trying to find a closed form for $R_n(u,x)$ but you have been much quicker. Even if there is a closed form for the numerator, I think the exact form is too complicated to use in full for my need, so I will try to look for approximations. For what it's worth, I don't think the lowest order $O(x^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor})$, numerically, it seems to decay slower than exponentially in $n$.

Comment: See the earlier comment for my current belief about the lowest order. The $O(x^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor})$ was a statement about how far I believe the terms given to be accurate. E.g. for $n = 6$ there is a discrepancy from the given value in the $x^3$ term. Also, to report the little further progress I've made, in the polynomials in $n$ giving the coefficients of $x^{n-i}$ the first term appears to be $(2i-1)!!$ and the second one appears to have a closed expression in terms of factorials and double-factorials, but the third one doesn't. I suspect it's a sum of two or more such expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the generating functions
$$
R_k(u) = \sum_{j_1,\ldots,j_k\geq 0} u^{j_1 + 2 j_2 + \cdots + k j_k} \prod_{t=1}^k \frac 1{j_t! t^{j_t}} f_t(j_1,\ldots,j_t).
$$
I will prove by induction on $k$ that
$$
R_k(u) = \frac 1 u + (1-\frac 1u) \exp(u+\frac {u^2}2+\cdots+\frac {u^k}k) =  \frac {u^k}{k+1} + O(u^{k+1}).
$$

Note that the first formula implies the second one. Indeed, we have
$$
(1-\frac 1u) \exp(u+\frac {u^2}2+\cdots+\frac {u^k}k+\frac {u^{k+1}}{k+1}+\cdots) = (1-\frac 1u) \exp(-\ln(1-u)) = -\frac 1u.
$$
Terms with $u^{k+2}$ and higher do not contribute to $u^k$ and lower, so we get
$$
(1-\frac 1u) \exp(u+\frac {u^2}2+\cdots+\frac {u^k}k+\frac {u^{k+1}}{k+1}) = -\frac 1u +O(u^{k+1})
$$
and
$$
(1-\frac 1u)  \exp(u+\frac {u^2}2+\cdots+\frac {u^k}k) = -\frac 1u \exp(-\frac {u^{k+1}}{k+1}) +O(u^{k+1}) = -\frac 1u +\frac {u^k}{k+1}+O(u^{k+1}).
$$

The base of induction $k=1$ is rather easy, we get
$$R_1 = \sum_{j\geq 0}\frac {u^j}{j!} \frac j{j+1}$$
$$=\exp(u) - \sum_{j\geq 0}\frac {u^j}{(j+1)!} = \exp(u) + \frac {\exp(u)-1}u$$
and the statement follows.

To prove the induction step $k\to (k+1)$ observe that
$$
R_{k+1}(u) = R_k(u) \exp(\frac {u^{k+1}}{k+1}) - u^k( {\rm Coeff.~of~}R_k{\rm~at~}u^k)
\Big(\sum_{j\geq 0} \frac {u^{j(k+1)}}{(j+1)! (k+1)^j}\Big)
$$
(using the induction assumption)
$$= R_k(u) \exp(\frac{u^{k+1}}{k+1})
-\frac {u^k}{k+1} 
\Big(\frac{\exp(\frac {u^{k+1}}{k+1})-1}{\frac {u^{k+1}}{k+1}}\Big)
$$
$$
=(R_k(u)-\frac  1u)\exp(\frac {u^{k+1}}{k+1}) + \frac 1u
$$
$$
=\frac 1 u + (1-\frac 1u) \exp(u+\frac {u^2}2+\cdots+\frac {u^{k+1}}{k+1}).
$$

It remains to observe that the coefficient of $R_n(u)$ at $u^n$ is exactly the original formula.

Comment: I have not tried to work with the $S(n,x)$. Presumably, the method will still provide something, but I don't know how explicit it will be.

Comment: More generally, it seems that $$R_k(u) = \sum_{d=k}^{2k} \frac{u^d}{d+1} + O(u^{2k+1}).$$

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. The point is that only "linear" terms in the exponentials contribute.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: Your "More generally" claim easily follows from Lev's proof, because if we set $f := \sum_{d=1}^k \dfrac{u^d}{d!}$ and $g := \sum_{d=k+1}^\infty \dfrac{u^d}{d!}$, then $f+g = -\log\left(1-u\right)$ and therefore $\exp\left(f+g\right) = \dfrac{1}{1-u}$, so that $\exp f \cdot \exp g = \exp\left(f+g\right) = \dfrac{1}{1-u}$ and therefore $\left(1-u\right) \exp f = \dfrac{1}{\exp g} = \exp\left(-g\right) \equiv 1-g \mod u^{2k+2}$ (since $g$ is divisible by $u^{k+1}$, and thus $\left(-g\right)^i \equiv 0 \mod u^{2k+2}$ for all $i \geq 2$). The rest you can figure out easily :)

Comment: Nice proof, Lev! You can probably start your induction at $k=0$, though.

Comment: I am sure you are right :)

Comment: @darijgrinberg, to start the induction at $k=0$ you need $R_0(u) = 1$, which is exceptional in that as defined it would be an empty sum.

Comment: @PeterTaylor No, it would not be an empty sum. There is exactly one 0-tuple.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, point conceded: the sum limits can be rewritten as $j \in \mathbb{N}^k$ to make this clearer. Lev, extending this to include $x$ I get $$R_k(u,x) = \exp(ux + \tfrac{u^2 x}2 + \cdots + \tfrac{u^kx}k) - \sum_{i=1}^{k} iS_{i-1}(x) \frac{\exp(\tfrac{u^ix}i) - 1}{ux} \exp(\tfrac{u^{i+1}x}{i+1}+\cdots+\tfrac{u^k x}k)$$ where $S_k(x) = [u^k] R_k(u,x)$ is the $S(k,x)$ of the question. The part outside the sum is easy and gives the upper bound $\binom{x+k-1}{k}$ already noted and improved upon, but the parts in the sum are less easy.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I would try to compute the first few $R_k(u,x)$ to see if there is a pattern. For example, it is easy to see that $R_k(u,x) = c_k(x) u^k  + O(u^{k+1})$, so  there is hope for some structure.

Comment: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwtjc1uwkAMhM_Zp5ijTZs_9YZIn4EkqsSpElIdulpw0JIV4e1xCJZsWf5mPJ3X06HYzd9osB_PDx0v_nju7Epty25ZfopdWvFdYi_Ry-3Fl3Fg5_5kQEeBty7zAwKaBtUWUaYUFTU-UG2Sy8Q-UPoN2GBGicCFzFdil72FYsC-5DUjB4kN20ok69nQ4utfeA3s18C3eYkvbv9-mCgPTJWJhjFC4RXxqCeh-svksLpGrxPpp3mU-QmQEUXi&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ== computes the first 12 and is easily extended, although I think the PowerSeriesRing constructor needs modification to use higher orders of $u$ if you want to get beyond about 18. I've spent a few hours with this and not seen anything which isn't easier to show directly.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see any pattern either. Perhaps there is a pattern for R_k'(u,1).

Comment: Nah, don't see it even for the first derivative.

Comment: Thank you for the very nice answer and the insight about the $x\neq 1$ case!

Answer (score 2):

This is just an extended comment providing an alternative view at $S(n)$, which (I hope) may lead to a solution.

Notice that $f_t(j_1,j_2,\dots,j_t) = 1-\frac{\delta_{j,t}}{1+j_t}$,
where
$$\delta_{j,t} := \big[j_1+2j_2+\dots+(t-1)j_{t-1} = t-1\big]$$
is an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Let $\bar n:=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and for a given partition exponents $j=(j_1,\dots,j_n)$ with $j_1 + 2j_2+\dots+nj_n=n$, define $J(j) := \{t\in\bar n\,:\,\delta_{j,t}=1\}$. Then
\begin{split}
(n+1)! S(n)&=(n+1)!\sum_{j:\ j_1 + 2j_2+\dots+nj_n=n}  \prod_{t=1}^n \frac{1}{j_t!t^{j_t}} \sum_{T\subseteq J(j)} (-1)^{|T|} \prod_{t\in T} \frac1{j_t+1} \\
&= \sum_{T\subseteq \bar n} (-1)^{|T|} \sum_{j:\ j_1 + 2j_2+\dots+nj_n=n\atop J(j)\supseteq T} \prod_{t=1}^n \frac{(n+1)!}{(j_t + [t\in T])!\,t^{j_t}}.
\end{split}
The last formula may be viewed as application of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) under a suitable combinatorial interpretation of its terms, which then would likely imply the needed $(n+1)!S(n)=n!$ out of the box. Unfortunately, I was not able to find such an interpretation so far, but have a gut feeling it's out there.